# iOS Objective-C dynamic cell height iOS 7 issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating an application with **iOS 7** devices. This application contains `UITableView` with **dynamic cell height**.

To create this I have a custom cell which contains methods:

```
- (CGFloat)heightWithModel:(Model *)model
{
    CGFloat height = 0.0f;

    height = self.contentLabel.frame.origin.y + [self contentHeightWithModel:model] + CellBottomOffset;

    return height;
}
```

and...

```
- (CGFloat)contentHeightWithModel:(Model *)model
{
    CGFloat height = 0.0;

    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    NSString *string = model.content;
    NSStringDrawingContext *context = nil;
    NSStringDrawingOptions options = NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin;
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.contentLabel.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);

    CGRect frame = [string boundingRectWithSize:size options:options attributes:attributes context:context];

    height = frame.size.height;

    return height;
}
```

In my view controller, I have implemented `UITableViewDelegate` protocol method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat height;

    static Cell *cell;

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellReuseIdentifier];
    }

    height = [cell heightWithModel:[self.dataSource.models objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return height;
}
```

As far as I understand, this should be enough to create a table view with dynamic cell height. Despite this, I have a table view like this:

[image]

As you see, part of text are hidden, because label (red one) height is too small. Cell height is set dynamically by using **Auto Layout** (10 px from the bottom).

Can anyone see where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

[image: See that your label height increase like this]

First take a variable

**CGFloat height;**

put this lines in **viewdidload** method

in that set estimated height of cell and for that label set lines to 0 in inspector panel and change its height = to >= and give constraint from all side

> ```
> [self.tbl_rating layoutIfNeeded];
>
>   [self.tbl_rating setNeedsLayout];
>
> if (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1 )
> {
>     self.tbl_rating.estimatedRowHeight=153.0f;
>     self.tbl_rating.rowHeight=UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
> }
> ```

Now put this two method for finding label height and dynamic cell height increment

In this method set your label text that you retriving from like array or web service

> ```
>  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
> // 7.1>
>
> if (NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1 ) {
>
> height=[self findHeightForText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arr_review valueForKey:@"desc"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] havingWidth:self.view.frame.size.width andFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f]].height;
>
>      return 153+height;
>
> }   
> return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
>
>
>  }
>
>
>
>
> -(CGSize)findHeightForText:(NSString *)text havingWidth:(CGFloat)widthValue andFont:(UIFont *)font {
>
>
> CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
> if (text) {
>
>
>     CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font } context:nil];
>
>
>     size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, ceil(frame.size.height));
> }
>
>
> return size; 
>
> }
> ```

NOTE: In ***tableview*** method **heightForRowAtIndexPath** I recommand you pass text from array value. If this thing doesnt work then check your constraints.

This thing works for me Hope it will work.
Thank you.